# Proplem with Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have been having problem with my visual studio 2015 community edition especial with visual c++. I notice that whenever I enter Developer Command prompt it shows:

> 'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. 'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>

and I already have mysql in my ordinary command prompt. I also can't access `cmake` through developer command prompt

Comment: Check your environment variables, both before using the Developer Command and during.  See if the `path` is set up correctly for MySQL.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have checked my environment variable and MySQL is in the path. I can access my MySQL through ordinary command prompt but I can't through developer command prompt not only MySQL I can't access any user defined path through developer command prompt. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution mysql fabric messed up my path by adding it's directory to the path without parenthesis